# Facebook sharer, pass in a comment?

Tags: facebook, share

Is it possible to post a description/comment variable to the facebook sharer url? It's only possible for url and title as far as I can figure out.

UPDATE:

Quotes/Comments were [decommissioned from Facebook Sharer URLs](https://github.com/nygardk/react-share/issues/456) in mid 2022.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a program? If so perhaps you should rephrase the question so that it is a question about the Facebook API.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The parameters that you can pass to the actual `sharer.php` are "u" and "t" which are `url` and `title`.  You can add `meta` tags to your page to get more info to appear in the sharer.  To quote the [docs](http://www.facebook.com/share_partners.php) (make sure you click the advance partners link):

> In order to make sure that the preview
>   is always correctly populated, you
>   should add the tags shown below to
>   your html. An example news story could
>   have the following:
>
> ```html
> <meta name="title" 
>       content="Smith hails 'unique' Wable legacy">
> <meta name="description" 
>       content="John Smith claims beautiful football ..." />
> <link rel="image_src" 
>       href="http://www.onjd.com/design05/images/PH2/WableAFC205.jpg" />
> ```
>
> As shown, title contains the preview
>   title, description contains the
>   preview summary and image_src contains
>   the preview image. Please make sure
>   that none of the content fields
>   contain any html markup because it
>   will be stripped out. For
>   consistency's sake, please use the
>   <meta> tag to provide text data for
>   the preview, and the <link> tag for
>   any source urls.
>
> The title and summary tags are the
>   minimum requirements for any preview,
>   so make sure to include these two.

Comment: I don't think Facebook actually checks the "t" paramter anymore and instead just checks the meta tags on the site as I'm unable to change the title to something else.

Comment: @JackMarchetti: Thanks, that explains a few things! :-) The "share" button is actually no longer officially supported and they're trying to get webmasters to use the "like" button instead.

Answer (score 15):

You can actually pass custom title, url, image and comment/description using:

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titlehere&p[url]=http://www.yoururlhere.com&p[summary]=yoursummaryhere&p[images][0]=http://www.urltoyourimage.com
```

Answer (score 1):

As shown, title contains the preview title, description contains the preview summary and image_src contains the preview image. Please make sure that none of the content fields contain any html markup because it will be stripped out. For consistency's sake, please use the `<meta>` tag to provide text data for the preview, and the `<link>` tag for any source urls.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sharer use the description `meta` tag to add a description in your post for the pictures. I don't really know how it works but I think it uses this tag in your header:

```html
<link rel='image_src' href='http://www.yourwebsite/dir1/dir2/picture.jpg' />
```

Comment: there's a probleme when sending html code in this board so here's the tag for the picture:

<link rel=&#39;image_src&#39; href=&#39;http://www.yourwebsite.com/dir1/dir2/picture.jpg&#39; />